# How to install VScode extensions using npm?

Tags: npm-install, visual-studio-code

Our development environment is very secured, It doesn't have access to public internet and limited with the installation of software and tools.

Since the npm registry is mirrored to our intranet, we are allowed to install the node modules.

The VS code is not listing any extensions. Is there any way that I can add the Extensions like "prettier" using `npm install` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible since VS code extensions are not published to npm (or, at least, they should not be).

You best option is probably to download the extension vsix files from the marketplace for offline use and [install them manually](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix)